# Canada Permanent Residency: Express Entry and Ontario Nominee Programs

Tags: canada, immigration

It is around 2 years that I have immigrated to Canada (Ontario). Currently I have a valid work permit until 2018 but I want to apply for permanent residency.

I got confused about different programs that are available to me. I have the master of science in computer science from a Canadian University and currently I am working in a good company as software developer.

I noticed that there are two main programs that I can apply for them: Express Entry and Ontario nominee program (OINP) and each program has a number of sub programs (confusing).

I am wondering which one I should apply considering the processing time, chance of success, and fees.

Comment: You should search and/or ask a moderator to move this post to the [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com). There's been several posts in the last year on the Express Entry system.

Comment: @mkennedy, thank you for the suggestion. I did not know that community exists. I try to move it to Expatriates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IANAL (I am not a lawyer), and I'm also not a Canadian, nor an expert on Canadian immigration. I have looked at the Express Entry websites and some provincial nomination websites, so please take this answer as incomplete but possibly useful.

The express entry "point limits" on the draws so far this year have been running around 450 - 800 points. Because you have a job, that significantly adds points to your total. I would suggest finding the pages where you can add up your points and see what your total would be.

You can concurrently apply for OINP and if you receive it, add more points to your Express Entry total. However, is there some reason you cannot apply for the Masters Graduates Stream of the OINP? The biggest hurdles I see are the $1500 cost, you have to be within 2 years of graduation, and possibly your company may have to be approved and have your job approved for the OINP.

OINP is currently closed for this Stream until January 4, 2016.

You also might talk to your HR department to see if they've had temporary work permit employees convert to permanent residents in the past. They have ideas on the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very helpful for me to make sure what I am thinking is correct. Did you see somewhere that it is possible to apply for both express entry and OINP at the same time? I think I can apply only to one of them.

Comment: I have all requirements of Masters Graduates Stream, but I think I should stay in Ontario if I apply with OINP and there is a chance that I move to British Colombia (another province of Canada). So I am not sure if it is true or not?